# PicklingError while defining some functional operators

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, pickle

I am using a math software SageMath, based on Python 2.7. The following simplified code is to recursively compute two functions starting from their initial estimations. When I try to introduce a "numerical integral operator" to the code, instead of using the built-in functions, it gives an error:

```
> PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __ builtin__.function failed
```

the code is:

```
reset()
forget()
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

#variables
var('x,y, x1,y1')
N=5   #number of iterations
var('q')

#functions' name definition (without specifying the rules)  # n is the level of estimation
U0=[]
U1=[]
for n in range(N+1):
    U0.append(function('U0_%s' %i, x,y))
    U1.append(function('U1_%s' %i, x,y, x1,y1))

#initial estimation of the functions
U0[0]=sin(x+y)
U1[0]=sin(x1+y1)*cos(x-y)


#numerical integrator
num=20.0  # at each call of the int function h is assigned (b-a)/num, so assigned to num here
def numint(f, x, a, b, h):
    #pickle_function(f)
    integ = 0.5*h*(f(x=a) + f(x=b))
    for i in range(1,num):
        integ = integ + h * f(x=a+i*h)
    return integ


#the integral operators
def Ix(f,x):
    return pool.apply( numint, (f,x,-1.0,+1.0,2.0/num) )
def Iy(f,y):
    return pool.apply_async( numint, (f,y,-1.0,+1.0,2.0/num) )
def IR(f,x,y):
    return Iy(Ix(f,x),y)
def N0(n,f0,f1):
    return f0[n] + IR(f1[n],x1,y1) + IR(IR(f1[n],x,y),x1,y1)
def N1(n,f0,f1):
    return f1[n] + IR(f0[n],x,y) - IR(IR(f1[n],x,y),x1,y1)


#the calculations
pool = Pool(processes=cpu_count())
for n in range(N):
    worker0 = N0(n,U0,U1)
    worker1 = N1(n,U0,U1)
    U0[n+1] = U0[n] - worker0.get()
    U1[n+1] = U1[n] - worker1.get()
    show(U0[n+1])
    show(U1[n+1])
```

As far as I have understood from searching the web and reading the documents this pickling error is either due to the integral operator (a function anyway) not being Picklable or due to its arguments not being picklable. I tried to make the operator itself picklable at no success, but I guess the problem should be due to the integral operator itself being a functional of its integrand, and as it is an *operator* the function in its integrand is not to be determined since the very beginning, so maybe the first argument of the operator (which itself is a function) not being clearly defined at top level is the reason for the operator not being in overall picklable? Any idea how to overcome this error?

**NOTE**. the main code is much more complex than the minimalistic code provided here, so I rather need to define an integral operator to prevent the code's readability.

Comment: I tried to first reproduce the error, then to further minimize it to what goes wrong. But the code you provide does not run and it is unclear where things like `reset()`, `forget()`, `var()` and `function()` do come from. So can you either extend this so it will run (and fail) or give a further minimized example that runs?

Comment: @Anthon, I guess that the code is not reproducible for you is due to the fact the it is not pure Python, but SageMath, a software over Python, that should explain why no extra library is required to be called for functions like sin() and etc. Also 'reset()', 'forget()' and 'var()' are used in working with symbolic variables and assumptions. However, the code works when I use the symbolic built-in integral operator 'integral()', it only fails when I use my own integral operator numint(). Does that make sense?

Comment: thanks for the details. I edited your OP, so the type function can actually be seen and is not suppressed as a HTML tag -- Have you tried simplefying the `numint` to something like `return a` to see if that works? Did you have a look at `http://ask.sagemath.org/question/1229/how-to-save-a-function-in-sage`, I only found that after discovering that part of your error message was missing (but visible when editing the post).